# miscalculating times - strtotime, date() - PHP

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

Calculating time using date and strtotime functions.

```
$starttime = '11:55';
$endtime = '13:01'; //or '1:01'
$totaltime = date("i",strtotime($endtime) - strtotime($starttime));
```

I don't know why, but `echo $totaltime` giving `06` instead of `66`

Its working fine on other time frames. i.e for `12:30, 13:30`

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your return value is formatted as a new time output (because of the date() function)

As you are only requesting the number of minutes in the formatted time, it's only returning that part.

If you want to see the hours and minutes, output using h:

```
$totaltime = date("H:i",strtotime($endtime) - strtotime($starttime));
```

This will return "01:06".

If you need the actual number of minutes between two dates (so you want 66 as outcome) then you're not looking for a formatted time-string as an outcome, but rather a regular integer holding the number of minutes. This you can calculate from your earlier calculation, like this:

```
// divide total seconds between these points by 60, round down.
$totalMinutes = floor ( ( strtotime($endtime) - strtotime($starttime) ) / 60 );
```

Comment: I only need minutes, like 66 should be in this case.

Comment: Then multiply the hours by 60 then add the minutes

Comment: @Erik when $endtime="01:01" its returning -654

Comment: Yes, because the $endtime in that case is before the $starttime, so the number of minutes passed will be negative.

Answer (score 2):

Because date("i") only shows minutes from 0 to 59.

[PHP date manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

A possible solution:

```
$totaltime = (strtotime($endtime) - strtotime($starttime)) / 60;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$starttime = '11:55';
$endtime = '13:01';
echo $totaltime (strtotime($endtime) - strtotime($starttime)) / 60;
echo $totaltime = floor ((strtotime($endtime) - strtotime($starttime)) / 60);

?>
```

[image]

Comment: when $endtime="01:01" its returning -654

Comment: echo $totaltime = floor ((strtotime($endtime) - strtotime($starttime)) / 60);

Comment: Yes using the same... returning negative value